# Why is webbrowser.open not working in repl.it?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser, replit

For a python project I'm using repl.it for a text-adventure game.

But `webbrowser.open('url went here')` is not working in repl.it. It's not opening the web page page.

Any idea why?

Comment: The `webbrowser` can only open a URL in a browser on the *same computer as where Python is running*. repl.it doesn't run on your computer, it runs on a computer in a large datacenter somewhere else, and it almost certainly doesn't have any browsers installed to open the URL in.

Answer (score 1):

repl.it does't run your code on your computer, it runs the code in a "large datacenter somewhere else". The code wouldn't open URLs on your computer because that isn't where the processes are being run.

It is the same with sounds, you can't play them on repl.it either.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the support engineers of replit, and they said "This is actually intended behavior for both security and performance reasons."